# Autenticación por teléfono no funciona (Firebase - Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-auth

Tengo un problema en la autenticación de firebase.
Realizo los pasos como los trae la guía que proporciona firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth

En todos los dispositivos se ejecuta el método "onCodeSent", pero solo a algunos les llega el mensaje. Parece que la compañía no tiene nada que ver, ni la marca del dispositivo.
Una cosa curiosa es que, si un dispositivo que no recibe mensaje pone el número de uno que si, si le llega al otro dispositivo, pero al poner el código para verificarlo, le marca que es incorrecto.

Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hace no mucho tuve el mismo inconveniente, mande un mail a soporte preguntando por qué no llegaban los mensajes ya que mi caso de uso era crucial que estos mensajes llegaran para poder usar la app.

Les comente sobre las distintas compañias telefónicas de mi región para que se hiciera un chequeo si estos tenian algun inconveniente recibiendo el mensaje.

Lo que si note fue que en modo debug de la app no llegaban siempre los mensajes, pero si generaba un apk de produccion y corría la app funcionaba normal, este tema tambien fue muchas veces debatido en el foro en inglés de StackOverflow

No existe una solución específica al problema, puede deberse a muchos factores, deberías probar en modo producción si los mensajes llegan bien, tambien recordá que si marcaste muchas veces un numero para que llegue un mensaje va a ser bloqueado por un tiempo de recibir mensajes por muchos intentos consecutivos.